# OverloadException in single node cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I read through this page : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesHintedHandoff.html and identified that `OverloadedException` in `Cassandra` is due to the

"`The coordinator tracks how many hints it is currently writing, and if the number increases too much, the coordinator refuses writes and throws the OverloadedException exception.`"

But I use a single node and able to get Overload exception frequently so what could be the reason for Overload exception in **singlenode** with `Consistency as 1 and ReplicationFactor as 1`?

**EDITED :**

Total hints In progress JMX

[image]

[image]

```
I checked in the code :

 private static void checkHintOverload(InetAddressAndPort destination)
    {
        // avoid OOMing due to excess hints.  we need to do this check even for "live" nodes, since we can
        // still generate hints for those if it's overloaded or simply dead but not yet known-to-be-dead.
        // The idea is that if we have over maxHintsInProgress hints in flight, this is probably due to
        // a small number of nodes causing problems, so we should avoid shutting down writes completely to
        // healthy nodes.  Any node with no hintsInProgress is considered healthy.
        if (StorageMetrics.totalHintsInProgress.getCount() > maxHintsInProgress
                && (getHintsInProgressFor(destination).get() > 0 && shouldHint(destination)))
        {
            throw new OverloadedException("Too many in flight hints: " + StorageMetrics.totalHintsInProgress.getCount() +
                                          " destination: " + destination +
                                          " destination hints: " + getHintsInProgressFor(destination).get());
        }
    }
```

1) Is this the only way to get the Overloaded exception ?
2) Why am I getting the Overload exception in single node ?
3) When this checkHintOverload method is called in Single node?

**NOTE** :

1) My Keyspace has been configured with NetworkTopologyStrategy, Will that be a reason? : `CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter_1': '1'} AND durable_writes = true;`

2) hinted_handoff = enabled in cassandra.yaml, Still I wonder will it trigger the hints in Single node, If so why?

3) consistency level is Quorum in this single node

Could any of the three parameter might be a reason for this?

Comment: Nope, hints is the only way to get that exception. Could you check the mbean "org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Storage name=TotalHintsInProgress"?

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson It is a single node, So there is no possibility of hints? Also where can I find the 'org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type' ?\

Comment: https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html You can use jconsole to see the values if you don't have another JMX client. There shouldn't be any hints since this is a singlenode but there is no other way this is possible.

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson I have added the Image in the same question, Could you tell me your observation from this? Also hinted_handoff = enabled in cassandra.yaml

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson Also consistency level is Quorum in this single node

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson One more information My keyspace has been configured with NetworkTopologyStrategy, Will that be a reason? : CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter_1': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;

Comment: That picture doesn't tell me much. You have to click on Attributes->Value to see the current value of the mbean.

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson I checked its value is showing as  0, But I added the NOTE : Will these be a reason for enabling hints in single node? I could run a test program and see whether the total hints value is increasing, But I would like to understand when the hints will be populated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171918/discussion-between-harry-and-simon-fontana-oscarsson).

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson Please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50588114/single-node-cassandra-behaving-like-multinode-cassandra and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50581115/cassandra-client-and-server-timeout