# Single node Cassandra behaving like multinode Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a single node Cassandra cluster which hits to `ReadTimeOutException` and  I observe the following logs in server which seems weird to me,

```
ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-91] 2018-05-29 12:09:53,023 ErrorMessage.java:338 - Unexpected exception during request
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 1 responses.
       at org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraRoleManager.getRole(CassandraRoleManager.java:489) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
       at org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraRoleManager.getRoles(CassandraRoleManager.java:269) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
       at org.apache.cassandra.auth.RolesCache.getRoles(RolesCache.java:66) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
       at org.apache.cassandra.auth.Roles.hasSuperuserStatus(Roles.java:51) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
       at org.apache.cassandra.auth.AuthenticatedUser.isSuper(AuthenticatedUser.java:71) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
```

It says **Operation timed out - received only 1 responses.**, In Single node why Its saying expecting more than one response? Could some explain pls.

**NOTE** : I have enabled different strategy for this `system_auth` keyspace

```
CREATE KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenterproc': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

and set consistency level as `LOCAL_QUORUM`

**Cassandra server version** : 3.0.8

Will this be a reason?

Answer (score 2):

GCs longer than the timeout (like the 9 second GCs you posted in other questions) can cause internal auth timeouts. Most likely it received the response, had the GC, then registered as timeout.

Comment: for clarification : the data is received in the coordinator but not send to the client? It's a single node it's not necessary to wait for response from other replicas then why there is a delay

Comment: GC or safepoint pause can occur at anytime, including between when the request was completed by the ReadStage and received by the data resolver but not yet returned to the client (in this case wasn't client but auth provider). Normally you just get a request timeout but the auth provider prints the full exception in log. If you have long pauses you will get timeouts.